# Asyncwrite error in node 9.x while trying to install any packages using npm (v6.2.1)?

Tags: node.js, npm

I am having Ubunutu 16.04 LTS and node version 9.x installed.
While I try to install any npm package with the usual command it give me following error .

```
npm ERR! asyncWrite is not a function
npm ERR! pna.nextTick is not a function

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-06-03T15_04_58_766Z-debug.log
```

Thanks for the help in Advance.

Comment: Might not be the solution you want, but downgrading to v8.x will fix your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try down grade your nodejs to 8.11.2

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n 8.11.2
```